# Java FileWriter with append mode

Tags: java, filewriter

I'm currently using `FileWriter` to create and write to a file. Is there any way that I can write to the same file every time without deleting the contents in there?

```
   fout = new FileWriter(
    "Distribution_" + Double.toString(_lowerBound) + "_" + Double.toString(_highBound) + ".txt");
    fileout = new PrintWriter(fout,true);
fileout.print(now.getTime().toString() + ", " + weight + ","+ count +"\n");
    fileout.close();
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Pass `true` as a second argument to `FileWriter` to turn on "append" mode.

```
fout = new FileWriter("filename.txt", true);
```

[FileWriter usage reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 9):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29), you can use the constructor to specify whether you want to append or not.

> public FileWriter(File file,
>                     boolean append)
>              throws IOException
>
> Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second
>   argument is true, then bytes will be
>   written to the end of the file rather
>   than the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

You can open the FileWriter in append mode by passing `true` as the second parameter:

```
fout = new FileWriter("Distribution_" + ... + ".txt", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You may pass true as second parameter to the constructor of FileWriter to instruct the writer to append the data instead of rewriting the file.

For example,

fout = new FileWriter(
    "Distribution_" + Double.toString(*lowerBound) + "*" + Double.toString(_highBound) + ".txt",**true**);

Hope this would solve your problem.