# File Writer overrides previous write Java

Tags: java, text, bufferedwriter

```
try {
                File file = new File(filePath+"usedcommands.txt");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(input+"\n");
                bw.close();
            } catch(Exception e) { System.out.println("can't write to usedcommands.txt..."); }
```

I'm writing to a txt file, but every time I run through the writing process it overrides what is already written there. How can I change my code so this part of the program doesn't override what is already there?

Comment: Read the javadoc of `FileWriter` constructors.

Comment: You can pass true in the FileWriter constructor to turn the append mode on. 

`FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("filename.txt", true);`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225146/java-filewriter-with-append-mode

Comment: @algorithmic sorry buddy, its not a duplicate

Comment: BufferdWriter does not do this.  FileWriter does this unless you tell it to append instead of overwriting.

Comment: @Arc Can you explain why it is not a duplicate because it looks like it to me? BTW You don't need to create a file just to append to it. It will create the file as required for you.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have nothing to do with that question. I can understand though your concern though.

Comment: @Arc I don't understand the question then because it answers it AFAIK.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm sorry I didn't check previous questions, my first instinct was to ask away. You are correct it does answer it.

Comment: @Arc no issues. sometimes it is hard to tell. i know that myself. a second pair of eyes always helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass true as a second argument to FileWriter to turn on "append" mode.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

Comment: +1 This should be the same as `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);` as the FileWriter will just turn the `String` back into a `File`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this it will work

```
fw = new FileWriter("fileName",true);
```

for more details on FileWriter see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)