# How can I write to an external text file without overwriting current content in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej, copyonwritearraylist

I am trying to write missed responses to an external text file. The below method stored responses not recognized into an external text file, but overwrites the previous content. How do I stop it from overwriting?

//The write a list method

```
       public void writeAList(ArrayList<String> list, String filename)
        {
            if(list != null) {
                try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename)) {
                    for(String item : list) {
                        writer.write(item.trim());
                        writer.write('\n');
                    }                    
                }
                catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Problem writing file: " + filename +
                                       " in writeAList");
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Null list passed to writeAList.");
            }
        }
```

//I am calling it in this method

```
public String generateResponse(ArrayList<String> words)
{
    Iterator<String> it = words.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        String word = it.next();
        String response = responseMap.get(word);
        if(response != null) {
            return response;
        }
    }
    //If we get here, none of the words from the input line was recognized
    //In this case, a default response is returned
    //The words not recognised are stored in "missed.txt"
    helper.writeAList(words,"missed.txt");
    return pickDefaultResponse();

}
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225146/java-filewriter-with-append-mode

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 
`new FileWriter(filename)`

try

```
new FileWriter(filename, true)
```

Which creates the file writer in append mode, see the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you need to replace:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename)
```

With:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename, true)
```

Where the extra parameter `true` is to enable the append mode.

Comment: perfect thank you, one more question, how do I make the responses go on a new line? currently it just writes everything as one line?

Comment: @ashutosh It looks like you are adding a new line ok , so it may just be the editor you are using to look at the file not showing \n as a new line try changing \n to \r\n