# How to write data from an array into a text file?

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a simple program which asks the user for his name, surname and age and then saves it to a text file, however the previous data gets deleted.
I am already reading the text file and can display it but I cant write it to the text file.

This is the code I am using:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class UserData{
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException{
    //Initialisations
    Scanner scan = new 
    Scanner(System.in);
    File UserData = new File(PATH OF FILE);
    BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(UserData));


    //Reader for Writer Old Data
    String text[] = new String[10];
    int count = 0;
    String path = PATH OF FILE;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        text[count] = line;
        count++;
    }

    PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(PATH OF FILE);    
    for (int I=0; I<text.length ; I++)
    {
        pr.println(text);
    }



    //Writer
    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    pr.println(name);
    b.newLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your surname");
    String surname = scan.nextLine();
    pr.println(surname);
    b.newLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your age");
    int age = scan.nextInt();
    pr.println(String.valueOf(age));
    pr.close();
}
```

}

Comment: So you need to append data to your current data file?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225146/java-filewriter-with-append-mode

new FileWriter(UserData, true);

Comment: I have tested you code and it write corretly a text file. You must sure that your file path is correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileWriter class has a constructor

```java
public FileWriter(File file,
          boolean append)
           throws IOException
```

Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object.

In Your code - Change line no 9 to

```java
BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(UserData),true);
```

> If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

Here is the specification:
[Class FileWriter Constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean))