# How to stop file writer from overwriting text that already exists inside the document? Java

Tags: java

So as the title says, I have a file writer and I want to reuse the program multiple times and saving the text onto a new line in the same text document.

Code:

```
        try {
        File password1 = new File("password.txt");
        if (password1.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("File created: " + password1.getName());                         //Creates new file and inputs variables
        } else {
            System.out.println("File already exists:");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (save) {
        try {
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("password.txt");                       //Saves newly created file as a txt
            myWriter.write(web + ": " + password);
            myWriter.close();
            System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java FileWriter with append mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225146/java-filewriter-with-append-mode)

Comment: Maybe read the documentation? [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,boolean))

Comment: I think just checking just before writing that does the file with that name exist and if existing you can use `hasnextLine()` method of `Scanner` class to check is there something already written or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FileWriter(File file, boolean append): Creates a FileWriter object
> using specified File object. If the second argument is true, then
> bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the
> beginning. It throws an IOException if the file exists but is a
> directory rather than a regular file or does not exist but cannot be
> created, or cannot be opened for any other reason

you need to add second parameter to your constructor to enable the append mode:

```
  FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("password.txt", true);
```

Comment: [Is it my duty to check for duplicate questions before answering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326622/is-it-my-duty-to-check-for-duplicate-questions-before-answering)

Comment: Thanks this worked, is there any chance you know how to make the text go onto a new line?

Comment: @RhysKeown you can use BufferedWriter class for that. BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(myWriter);  and then br.newLine(); br.write(text);